# If acceleration is equivalent to gravitation, And all mass of the universe was condensed?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, acceleration, atomic-physics

If acceleration is equivalent to gravitation, And all mass of the universe was condensed then what would the effect of motion be in atoms ? In the rate of expansion would this have a exponential decrease in the rate of expansion ?
And the inverse of that would the amount of matter in one area affect the rate of compression ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that you are asking how mass and gravity affect the expansion and crunch of the universe.

1. acceleration is the effect of a gravitational field around a mass
2. the universe is expanding and this expansion is accelerating, bot only in regions where there is no mass, so in between galaxy clusters
3. inside galaxies, the expansion is not strong because mass and gravity has a stronger effect
4. it is the vacuum's negative density or dark energy that makes the expansion accelerate

Gravity is a force that is very weak in short range, that is why the EM, and the strong force are much stronger at the level of atoms.

If all the mass was condensed, then that part of the universe where the mass is, would feel no expansion at all, but very strong gravity on the macro level. But at the level of atoms, the EM repulsion between electrons and nuclei is much stronger, and that gives at the macrolevel stiffness to things.

Gravity is the force that keeps particles together but it is not strong enough to crush atoms, because the EM force is much stronger at the micro level.

What you are asking, is that gravity would keep in that case everything in one region of space, but it would not crush things together at the micro level, because EM repulsion is stronger. In that region, there would be no expansion though. But all other regions of space would expand because there would be no mass and dark energy would be strong.

The rate of compression would be strong but the micro level would still not be crushed into a singularity, or at least that would depend on the allocation of different particles.

I think your question is if all the matter was condensed into one area, would that create a black hole, and a singularity, and the answer is maybe, but it depends on the allocation of particles, and how small of a region you would condense the mass into.

Comment: So the size of the condensed mass would be equal to the distance of a atom from another atom of all the matter in the universe, equally spread into a spherical shape due to spherical symmetry and equilibrium  ? Which as long as the EM repulsion remains stronger than gravity at any ratio of mass to volume (density) then the rate of motion at the atomic level would be mesurable unlike what is talked about in different ideas of what time is in space and how its observed

Comment: The first sentence is yes, but there would be different types of atoms, and the ones closer to the centre would create heavier atoms, having more pressure. The second sentence is yes if the spreading of different atoms would be equally allocated everywhere, so every region would have the same gravitational field. In this case time would flow everywhere with the same rate, yes, and GR would still be true, but there would be no differences in gravitational fields, and time would flow everywhere at the same rate. I mean everywhere with mass. Outside, where is no mass, time would tick faster.

Comment: Actually at the center point, you would feel weightless, there would be no acceleration. Now about acceleration and the flow of time. If everything would be so close, that atoms would form a single macro "star" or "planet", then GR says, that time would tick slower closer to the center of gravity.

Comment: So the only reason multiple ideas of time and time rate exist is due to the reasoning that matter is spread out over the universe? And the areas of expansion that consist of a perfect vacuum are points of nothing or would these areas possibly be areas of zero kelvin ? And how would conservation of energy apply. would neutrinos and anti neutrinos be acceptable in these areas of essentially nothing ? would you recommend any articles or text about this ? I will stop dragging this on, on this thread.

Comment: The reason is that, mass is spread out unequally, with empty spaces within, and there are bigger and smaller masses. Bigger masses create stronger gravitational fields, slow time more relatively. That is why time rates exist "randomly", there is no direction where time would tick slower or faster. Now in your case, there would be such a direction, towards the center time would tick slower. Areas outside would be perfect vacuum, yes with dark energy. Yes, any pair of particles and antiparticles is acceptable, since pair creation is happening everywhere. That still has conservation of energy.

Comment: The reason there is more matter then antimatter is baryon asymmetry. I think GR would be (especially time dilation, and the four vector), and elementary particles (forces), and atomic systems (how they build up), and universe expansion (dark energy), I would search on this site, very good articles. You can learn almost anything. if you like my answer please upvote.

Comment: Ok, I now have another question to be post and I upvoted but I have less than 15 rep.